# How to return more than one value from a sub routine in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to read a config file in a separte subroutine and trying to call that in my main function. The subroutine return three variables(two arrays and one hash).Below is the code.

```
sub read_config{
my @keys; 
my @dbkeys; 
my %config; 
open CONFILE,'/usr/local/pbiace/current/comparator/cfg/configFile.cfg' or die $!; 
warn info_H . "opening config file \n ";
warn info_H . "reading postion info";
@keys=split '\|',<CONFILE>; 
(  $config{$keys[0]}, 
   $config{$keys[1]}, 
   $config{$keys[2]}, 
   $config{$keys[3]}, 
   $config{$keys[4]}, 
   $config{$keys[5]},
   $config{$keys[6]},
   $config{$keys[7]}) = split '\|',<CONFILE>; 
warn info_H. "reading config file to obatin DB connection details"; 
@dbkeys=split '\|',<CONFILE>; 
(  $config{$dbkeys[0]}, 
   $config{$dbkeys[1]}, 
   $config{$dbkeys[2]}, 
   $config{$dbkeys[3]} ) = split '\|',<CONFILE>; 
warn info_H . "returning values read";
return(@keys,@dbkeys,%config);
}
```

I am calling it using the code below.

```
(@keys,@dbkeys,%config)=read_config();
```

but this is not working.can anybody help me to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that perl squashes lists when passed back and forth. You can only return *one* list of results. See: [`perlsub`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Pass-by-Reference)

So the assignment to `@keys` will be 'eating' all the results from `read_config`, which isn't returning 3 data structures - it's returning one, containing all the elements in each.

The solution to this is to return by reference.

```
return ( \@keys, \@dbdkeys, \%config );
```

You then need to dereference them when you 'get' them:

```
my ($keys_ref, $dbkeys_ref, $config_ref)=read_config();

@keys = @$keys_ref;
@dbkeys = @$dbkeys_ref;
%config = %$config_ref;
```

Or just work with them as is, and dereference as you use them.

```
$keys -> [0];
$config -> {$key};
```

I would also point out - you should look at hash [slices](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) as that would probably improve your code - you can assign:

```
@config{@keys} = split ( '\|', <CONFILE> );
```

(But don't forget to `chomp` if you don't want a line feed!)

Comment: Hi, I tried the above code.
It's throwing the below error.
 Not an ARRAY reference at comparator_sub.pl line 73.
line 73 contains @dbkeys = @$dbkeys_ref;

Comment: @nithin Did you change the `return` from the subroutine to actually return references? I suspect not...

Comment: Yes.that was the mistake.I was not returning the reference for one array.It's working.Thank you very much.